# XCode 4.2.1 no response in apps store

Tags: xcode, macos, app-store

I am using Mac OS X Lion 10.7.2. I am trying to download and install XCode 4.2.1. Once I clicked the "Install" button, it go back to desktop screen and showing an "Download" icon. Because I am new to Mac, so I dont know whether I should click that icon to start download or is downloading. So i just leave it there.

Few hours later, a notification dialog pop out and told me "installation start and restart". I approved it and it restart the PC. Now the problem is: I can't find any "Developer" folder or do not know where the XCode installed. I go back apps store and trying to click "Install" again, but it has no response.

Please help. Thanks for advance and sorry for my poor english.

regards,
Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is everything normal .. Bear in mind that after the download you have to install Xcode from the icon ***Install Xcode*** that you will find in your applications folder.

Then you will find XCode under : `/Developer/Applications`

from there you can create an alias on desktop, on dock or wherever you want .

Comment: I do not know either the xcode is downloaded or installed or not. So I just go back the mac appstore again and click "Install" button, but it has no response at all. So what should I do now to clear everything and redo again.

Comment: No. That is why I go back MacStore to click "install" again, but it has no response. I try to find the download link but every link lead me to Macstore. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the "Install Xcode" application in /Application after it has been downloaded from the App Store... you have to RUN that! It will begin the actual installation.

Comment: @Ahmed: The problem is there is no "Install Xcode" in Application folder, so i guess it didnt downloaded at all. But when go back the MacStore, it has a button "Install", i click it and it has no response.

Comment: Will it possible my country (Malaysia) is not allowed to download this version? If yes, any alternative?

Comment: @aleroot aaah ... happens sometimes...  @Martin try clicking on 'Purchased' in  App Store  and see if Xcode is ACTUALLY declared installed if it is not installed the button will be say "INSTALL" if it IS installed it wall be a grayed-out button `INSTALLED`  ... if it says `update` then try that...

Comment: @aleroot: Lol! I now see "XCode" in "Pause" mode, so I just click "Resume" in "Purchases" tab. Thanks. 
ps: Mac os is not as user friendly as what Jobs said :(